# Change appearance of a single view in a ListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I'm working on a music app. I want to **bold** the information of the song which is currently playing (ex. Google Play Music). There is a ListView of all songs, populated by a RelativeLayout of song info for each song. A song is played either by clicking on the ListView (which can play any song) or pressing previous or next (which will play an adjacent song).

I dont want to use a ScrollView because the song library could have a very large number of entries to display.

I need to be able to

- edit views based on a given position, which may be off screen
- keep one particular view bolded regardless of whether it's on screen or not (eg. I can't default the views to Typeface.NORMAL because scrolling away and back to a song will reset it)
- revert the previously playing song back to normal when playback has finished

I've look at GPM source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music/+/master/src?autodive=0) but I couldn't tell where it does this. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated :)

Comment: Use a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) and keep the index of the currently playing song and when you redraw the item of the index make the text bold and whatever else you need. (RecyclerView may even remember the state, meaning you can just use events and fire and forget. I can't remember it's behavior off head)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of whether you use `ListView` or `RecyclerView`, the general template of the solution will be the same: you should store a reference to either (a) the "currently playing" index or (b) the "currently playing" data item.

Let's look at what the solution would be if you were using `ListView` and saving the "currently playing" index.

Step one would be some variable to save what's currently playing. Maybe you use an `int` and treat the special value `-1` as meaning that nothing is playing.

```
private int currentlyPlayingPosition;
```

Whenever you change whatever song is currently playing, you update the value stored here (maybe `++currentlyPlayingPosition` when the user presses "next song", etc). You'll then also have to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to tell the `ListView` to re-draw itself so that the bolded song changes.

In your `getView()` method, you can check to see if the view you're drawing is the "currently playing" song, and change the typeface based on that:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
    ...
    if (position == currentlyPlayingPosition) {
        textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
    } else {
        textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);
    }
    ...
}
```

The overall steps are relatively simple:

- Track which song is currently playing (by index, by object reference, or some other way)
- Any time the currently-playing song changes, notify the adapter
- Inside `getView()` check if the song you're displaying is the currently-playing song, and show special UI if so